# How to input a 2D array in Keras-Python?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras, numpy-ndarray

I am very new to machine-learning and keras and was stuck on trying to input data; I have data which looks like:

```
[[[0.01363717 0.        ]
  [0.01577874 0.        ]
  [0.01463021 0.        ]]

 [[0.01577874 0.        ]
  [0.01463021 0.        ]
  [0.01006721 0.        ]]

 [[0.01463021 0.        ]
  [0.01006721 0.        ]
  [0.00762504 0.        ]]...]
```

The data's shape is: (1607, 3, 2). 
How can I pass:

```
 [[0.01363717 0.        ]
  [0.01577874 0.        ]
  [0.01463021 0.        ]]
```

as an input in a layer of 512 CuDNNLSTM cells?

Here is my whole network:

```
def create_model():
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(CuDNNLSTM(512, input_shape=(3,2), return_sequences=True, name='inputlstm1'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(CuDNNLSTM(512, return_sequences=True,name='lstm2'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(CuDNNLSTM(512, return_sequences=True,name='lstm3'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', name='dense1'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax', name='denseoutput2'))


    # Compile model
    model.compile(
        loss='mse',
        optimizer='adam',
        metrics=['accuracy'],
    )
    return model
```

And its fitting:

```
model=create_model()
history=model.fit(xtrain, ytrain,batch_size=1, epochs=5, validation_data=(xtest, ytest), verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building of keras layers includes specifying the shape of passed array, here the array shape to be trained is (3,2) with 1607 samples,

```
input_shape = (3,2)
X = LSTM(124, activation = 'sigmoid', name='layer1', dropout = 0.4) (temp)
```

If you want to use stacked LSTM, you can use this

```
input_shape = (3,2)
    X = LSTM(124, activation = 'sigmoid', name='layer1', dropout = 0.4,return_sequences=True) (temp)
    X = LSTM(64, activation = 'sigmoid', name='layer2', dropout = 0.4) (X)
```

**edit**

```
def create_model():
    model = keras.models.Sequential()

    model.add(keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(512, input_shape=(3,2), return_sequences=True, name='inputlstm1'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(512, return_sequences=True,name='lstm2'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))

    # The last layer of Stacked LSTM need not to return the input sequences
    model.add(keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(512,name='lstm3'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', name='dense1'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax', name='denseoutput2'))


    # Compile model
    model.compile(
        loss='mse',
        optimizer='adam',
        metrics=['accuracy'],
    )
    return model
```

Comment: My model uses 3 LSTM Layers (each 512 neurons) and 2 Dense Layers (32 and 1). I am getting this error on output: `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected output to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1607, 1)`

Comment: seems the error you got in the first layer only, either you passed test data for input or the number of samples , you need to pass the shape of array , plz post the network to have clear understanding

Comment: I updated the post - my model is there. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @MPatel I just modified your network, check the update

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can set `batch_size = 1` and Keras will take care of it. Just put the whole array to the model input.